# Типизация в python

Tags: python, модули, типизация

К сожалению, не знаю, на сколько заголовок соответствует описанной ниже проблеме, если вообще это можно считать за проблему.

Например, есть функция:

```
def handler(service , command, *args, **kwargs):
    if command not in ['create', 'update', 'delete', 'list']:
        ...
    service.do_smth()
```

Например, я знаю, что объект service это экземпляр определенного класса. При попытке вызвать метод класса я должен или в слепую вызывать метод, или лезть в модуль с классами и смотреть имена методов. С аргументами все еще хуже. Если в случае с методами, если начать их писать ide\редактор подскажет что писать дальше, то в случае с аргументами такого не происходит.

С недавнего времени, можно явно указывать тип, написав service: ServiceType. Это действительно решает проблему.

Аналогичная ситуация

```
[ print(x.attr) for x in api.get_smth() ]
```

Какой атрибут я хочу вывести приходится гадать, т.к тип объекта x не известен.

Вопрос следующий:
Я так полагаю что это нормальное явление, и плата за динамическую типизацию. Вопрос лишь в том, как с этим бороться? И как писать код.

Comment: Согласно идеологии вроде бы никак, [утиная типизация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) и всё такое. Мол, если у `x` есть нужный нам `attr`, то какая разница, какого типа `x`?)

Comment: А вообще по аналогии с `service: ServiceType` можно указать, какой тип данных возвращает `def get_smth(...) -> List[ServiceType]` — подробнее см. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html — и тогда по идее тип `x` будет известен. Я, правда, не знаю, поддерживают ли это IDE, но питон прописать это позволяет

Comment: Дополню, такая особенность питона, которая имеет свои плюсы и минусы. Кст, если нужно проверить тип объекта, то есть функции type() и isinstance(). Если нужно проверить есть ли у объекта атрибут, то есть функция hasattr. @andreymal, pycharm точно поддерживает, плюсом он подсказывает какие атрибуты есть у возвращаемого объекта и может выделять предупрждением те строки, в которых странное творится -- например: возвращаем список, а работать пытаемся как с строкой

Comment: Здесь проблема именно в удобстве написания код, а не в type или isintance. Во втором питоне нельзя указывать тип который возвращает функция, или тип аргументов. И люди же как-то жили.

Comment: @TorSen плохо жили :)

Comment: Жаль. Я до последнего надеялся, что я упустил какую-то делать. Видимо придется писать так.   
Спасибо.

Comment: @TorSen сильно с выводами не спешите, ещё не все питонисты отметились здесь, может кто чего дельного ещё подскажет)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хорошая IDE (бесплатный PyCharm) решает приведенные проблемы.
Да, надо тип параметров функции указывать, ну так и программировать проще (особенно возвращаясь к коду через годик-другой).
Тип возврата из некоторого get_smth() попытается вычислить сама IDE, но можно и явно указать, что тоже полезно для сопровождения и документирования.

Comment: По поводу параметров функций понял. Спасибо. Тип возврата, ни pycharm, ни atom с тонной установленных для python пакетами указывать не хотят. Пока сам не  указал тип. 
Такого поведения ведь быть не должно?

Comment: У меня в pycharm, когда курсор на ИМЕНИ функции Alt-Enter предлагает специфицировать возвращаемый тип. Ну еще автоматически возникает маленькая "лампочка", там те же команды.

Comment: Я вас не так понял. Я в фразу "вычислить сама IDE" внес немного другой смысл. Теперь все стало на свои места, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете определить тип объекта c помощью `type()` или проверить, что объект нужного типа с помощью `isinstance()`

```
def sum_two_ints(a, b):
    if isinstance(a, int) and isinstance(b, int):
        return a+b
    else:
        raise TypeError
```

Comment: Или я не правильно донес мысль, или вы не правильно поняли. Мне не проверка типов нужна. Мне нужно удобство при написании кода. чтобы при необходимости вызвать метод объекта, мне не приходилось лезть в модуль или пакет с объектом, и смотреть какие у него методы и аргументы.

Comment: @TorSen да, я неправильно понял. Но в код объекта можно не лезть, можно с помощью функции `dir()`, которая принимает объект, вывести список его методов и атрибутов.

Comment: @pinguin `dir()` выводит не весь список